# At what stage in the angularjs lifecycle is the DOM completely loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events, single-page-application

I'm trying to wrap a native JavaScript functionality around an angularjs module and I need to bootstrap some code on `DOMloaded` event handler.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
    //bootstrapper code
})
```

I'm a little confused if this is needed in the angular domain or not or maybe I might just be repeating something that has already been called by angular which I could have simply attached my code to. If I put the bootstrapper code in the module's run block, will it achieve the same effect, the docs says

> It is executed after all of the service have been configured and the injector has been created.

with respect to the `DOMLoaded` Event, has it already been fired at this time?

Anyone know anything about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`angular.module('myApp', []).run(function($rootScope) { });` is similar to `$(document).load(function() {});` in jQuery but if a part of the page is being rendered using XHR then `run()` method will not be helpful.

You either have to write your logic inside below event

```
angular.module('myApp', []).run(function($rootScope) {
   $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
      // here
   });
});
```

Or you better off writing a custom directive depending upon what you have to achieve.